# Impossible Platform in Impossible Mission

Tags: commodore-64, impossible-mission

Seriously, how the heck can I reach this platform? I cannot step over any of these gaps. All I can do is jump, and I can't seem to jump a short distance, so I always skip two gaps. How can I possibly reach the middle platform?

Is this an impossible mission?

[image]

Comment: Just for clarity, do you mean the platform with the computer on it? Also, for tagging purposes, what is this game called?

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but this appears to be the same room as appears at [5:25 in this YouTube walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivHFP3dJAkM&t=5m25s), and it certainly doesn't look impossible. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: The game is called "Impossible Mission"; there's only a tag for IM 2.

Comment: @gnovice, that video just answered my question, though I swear I tried stepping over a gap 100 times. If you post that video as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever gotten an email from the Commadore-64 tag.... awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a walkthrough I found on YouTube, and [this particular room is covered starting at 5:25](http://m.youtube.com/watch?t=5m25s&v=ivHFP3dJAkM). It appears that you are able to step/run across the gaps without having to jump, which allows you to easily reach the elevator platform in the center.